# How to call Python function in Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I have a python function which in turn has many other forton/c++ dlls calling to generate the output value. Now I want to call that function in Pyomo model as expression. Any help on that?

The example I have is:

```py
def mult(a,b):
    c = a * b
    return(c)

model.a = Var(initialize=1)
model.y = Param(initialize = 6)

def add(model):
    x = mult(value(model.a),3)
    return(x)

model.value1 = Expression(rule=add)

modelinit_cond1 = Constraint(expr=(model.value1 == model.y))

opt = SolverFactory('ipopt');
results = opt.solve(model, tee=True)
results.write()
```

Expectation is; ipopt would try finding the value of model.a given that the constraint is satisfied.

Note: The code above is simpler in order simplify the explanation but the real problem on similar grounds.

Many Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: It sounds like what you are trying to do is not a legal call from pyomo.  Can you post the "expression" that you are trying to build by editing your post?

Comment: @AirSquid thanks for your reply. I tried posting my problem above and tried simplifying the issue. thanks,